# Cannot create dbcontext when using a MySql database instead of Sql Server with .net core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to connect to a MySql database with .net core.
I was previously connecting to a sql server database and it was working well.

But now I got the following error message in program.cs on line :

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: PatrimoineClick.Data.DbInitializer Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: PatrimoineClick.Data.DbInitializer': Unable to resolve service for type 'PatrimoineClick.Data.PatrimoineClickDbContext' while attempting to activate 'PatrimoineClick.Data.DbInitializer'.
>
> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: PatrimoineClick.Data.DbInitializer Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: PatrimoineClick.Data.DbInitializer': Unable to resolve service for type 'PatrimoineClick.Data.PatrimoineClickDbContext' while attempting to activate 'PatrimoineClick.Data.DbInitializer'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: PatrimoineClick.Areas.General.Traitement Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: PatrimoineClick.Areas.General.Traitement': Unable to resolve service for type 'PatrimoineClick.Data.PatrimoineClickDbContext' while attempting to activate 'PatrimoineClick.Areas.General.Traitement'.)

I add the db context like this :

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
//builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
//    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySQL(connectionString));
```

The connectionString "DefaultConnection" is :

```
"DefaultConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;database=PatrimoineClick"
```

I'm using a XAMPP server with default configuration :

No password for user root.

I don't understand why the service is not created.

Thanks by advance,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok, I have removed images of errors. Is it ok ?

Comment: Could you add `PatrimoineClick.Data.DbInitializer`'s constructors code?

Comment: @SergeyNazarov, I have modified the description to give you the information

Comment: Still can't see `DbInitializer` code listing.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why the service is not created.

It would be nicer if you could include your `DbContext` class as well. However, the error telling us it faild to construct `PatrimoineClick.Data.DbInitializer`
Means, you might not intialize it in your program.cs or you may not construct your `options.UseMySQL` on `OnConfiguring`. Roughly, you need to include below code snippet inside your `ApplicationDbContext`

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(@"server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;database=PatrimoineClick");
    }
```

**Note:** It would be great if you could try to with password. Sometime, password might cause the issue based on the configuration of your MySql server, Thus, you can try this pattern as well [`"server=localhost;port=3305;database=parking;uid=root"`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

**Full Application DbContext:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(@"server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;database=PatrimoineClick");
    }
}
```

Or you can also try below format as well:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    }
```

You can check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#configuring-the-database-provider)

In addition, please make sure you have added, below nuget package while adding `mySql DB`

```
dotnet add package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql --version 6.0.2
```

You can download it from this [official link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) Or you can even add it from your visual studio nuget package manager as below:

[image]

**Update Program.cs:**

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
     options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});


builder.Services.AddTransient<DbInitializer>(); Or

builder.Services.AddTransient<IDbInitializer,DbInitializer>();
```

and

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITraitement, Traitement>();
```

If `DbInitializer` has the type `Interface` IDbInitializer. You can check the [dependency injection official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#overview-of-dependency-injection)